# How to insert paaswordbox value into database table?

Tags: wpf, passwordbox

I used PasswordHelper class to bind passwordbox with viewmodel but still property field is null at submit time. i tried with debugger but property doesn't getting value.

XAML Code..

```
<Page x:Class="ChatApp.View.Register"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  xmlns:se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ChatApp.ViewModel"
  xmlns:w="clr-namespace:ChatApp"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="347" d:DesignWidth="350"
Title="Register">
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:RegisterViewModel></vm:RegisterViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Height="317">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="63" />
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
        <RowDefinition Height="42*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="112*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="188*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="User ID :" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Password :" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,2,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Name" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Email ID :" Grid.Row="4" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,2,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Contact No :" Grid.Row="5" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,1,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Address :" Grid.Row="6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Designation :" Grid.Row="7" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding userID}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding password}"  Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtpassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding emailID}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,12,0" Name="txtEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding contact}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtContact" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding address}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" Name="txtAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding designation}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtDesignation" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Margin="0,1,0,0" />        
    <TextBlock Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,1,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="New Registration" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" />
    <Button Content="Register" Grid.Row="8" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,5,0,0" Name="btnSubmit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger  SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=btnSubmit}" EventName="Click">
                <se:CallMethodAction MethodName="SubmitDetail" TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=btnSubmit}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

here is my password helper class.

```
  public static class PasswordHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Password",
        typeof(string), typeof(PasswordHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPasswordPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Attach",
        typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, Attach));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsUpdatingProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsUpdating", typeof(bool),
       typeof(PasswordHelper));


    public static void SetAttach(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(AttachProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetAttach(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(AttachProperty);
    }

    public static string GetPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(PasswordProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
    }

    private static bool GetIsUpdating(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(IsUpdatingProperty);
    }

    private static void SetIsUpdating(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(IsUpdatingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;

        if (!(bool)GetIsUpdating(passwordBox))
        {
            passwordBox.Password = (string)e.NewValue;
        }
        passwordBox.PasswordChanged += PasswordChanged;
    }

    private static void Attach(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;

        if (passwordBox == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.OldValue)
        {
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged += PasswordChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, true);
        SetPassword(passwordBox, passwordBox.Password);
        SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your complete xaml code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/taylorleese/468331

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1.

XAML is case sensitive with regards to binding paths, but you have used lower cased property names in your XAML. (You can find out more from the 'Case and Whitespace in XAML' section of the [XAML Overview (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) page at MSDN.

> XAML is generally speaking case sensitive. For purposes of resolving backing types, WPF XAML is case sensitive by the same rules that the CLR is case sensitive. Object elements, property elements, and attribute names must all be specified by using the sensitive casing when compared by name to the underlying type in the assembly, or to a member of a type.

2.

You do not need to set the `Password` property of the `PasswordBox` in your `OnPasswordPropertyChanged` handler, although this shouldn't cause your described problem.